# Why does my loop ends after first execution

Tags: bash, blender

I am trying to loop through a csv file and execute `Blender` to render the output. I am new to bash and trying to figure out why the loop ends prematurely after just 1st rendering. I only see it render first image in the folder.

blend.csv

```
3123,test1
3124,test2
3125,test3
3126,test4
```

bash.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r id text
do
    echo "from csv $id $text"
    exec </Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender -b ImageText.blend --python ImpostScript.py -- $id $text
done <blend.csv
```

Comment: Because you have `exec` inside the loop.

Comment: ah I feel so dumb.. ty